# emacs cd for all splits

Tags: emacs, cd

In emacs you can do M-x cd to change the default directory.

I usually have 5 splits/windows, so the cd I do in the first split does't affect the others. What If I want the cd to affect all my splits/buffers.
Is there an alternative command I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built-in but it's not too hard to write the function by hand:

```
(defun cd-all-windows (dir)
  (interactive "Ddirectory: ")
  (dolist (window (window-list))
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
      (cd dir))))
```

Put that in your `.emacs` and you should be able to run `M-x cd-all-windows` to get the desired effect.